# Get multiline string from Python variables

Tags: python, list, listview

I have the following piece of code to get name and launch time for each instance:

```
for instance in instances:

    instance_name = instance.name
    launch_time = instance.launch_time
```

As result i want to get a variable with the list like:

```
instance_name: launch_time
instance_name: launch_time
...
```

i.e

```
Name: server1; Launch time: 2 days, 7:33:46.319073
Name: server2: Launch time: 4 days, 6:33:46.319073
...
```

and then use it for email notification in another multi-line string.
I've done it with:

```
result = []
result.append({'name':instance_name, 'launch_uptime':uptime })
```

but i don't like these quotes, i want a good formatted text

Comment: So you want a list of strings? or a dictionary? something else?...

Comment: Well formated text without quotes, and get each name and launch time on new line

Comment: What quotes do you mean?

Comment: from example above i'm getting:
{'launch_uptime': '2 days, 7:33:46.319073', 'name': 'exampleserver'}, {'launch_uptime': '2 days, 7:33:15.319133', 'name': 'testServer'}

but i want well formatted output like in examle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
multi_line = ''

for instance in instances:
    instance_name = instance.name
    launch_time = instance.launch_time

    multi_line += 'Name: ' + instance_name +'; Launch time: ' + launch_time + '\n'

print(multi_line)
```